# end the method that call this method

Tags: java

Is there a way to end the method that calls on the method that the code is in. Let me explain if you have some code like this.

```
int value;
value = method();
value = 3;
```

If I got it work like I want then the execution of the code would end on line 2 and line 3 would never be executed. basically it would be like there was a return between line 2 and 3. Is is something like this possible with Java?

Edit: Ok i think a lot of people have misunderstood me. The code that end the code on in this method on line 2 should be inside of method() and it should not be possible to avoid this outside this method if it's call inside of a try for example.

Comment: I guess you could throw an exception...

Comment: another alternative is set the value of int value to 3 at the first line of the method method() that way if nothing else modifies its value in that method you will get back 3. Avoids having to do the exception thing in method()

Comment: not understanding your question after your edit. By the way, having a value called value and a method called method is definately not helping the explanation....

Comment: Let say you have to method number one is code not visible inside my example but is call in the example by this line of code value = method();. So it return a int but when it does this it should also end method 2 that is shown in the example immediately, preventing code to run after this call to make sure it's always used last.

I hope this made it a little clearer.

Comment: I think you might be getting caught up in the _how_. Can you please explain _why_ you want to do this?

Comment: "to make sure it's always used last."

Comment: But why do you want it to always be used last? What is the use case?

Comment: I don't have any code were I "need" this, I'm interested if it's theoretically possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example is a bit abstract, a real one might result in better answers. In general though there are two ways this is normally achieved:

1. Return a special value e.g. -1

   ```
   int method() {
       if (/* something is wrong */) {
           return -1;
       }

       // Process as normal and return real value
   }

   ...

   int value;
   value = method();
   if (value == -1) {
       value = 3;
   }
   ```
2. Throw an exception in method()

   ```
   int method() throws IllegalStateException {
       if (/* something is wrong */) {
           throw new IllegalStateException();
       }

       // Process as normal and return real value
   }

   ...

   int value;
   try {
       value = method();
   } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
       value = 3;
   }
   ```

Comment: The problem with exception is that you can have the method call inside a try and in that case it wont be the last line of code. Is there really no other way to make sure this is the last line of code run by the method when it's called.

Comment: You could use a `RuntimeException`. They don't need to be explicitly caught or thrown by clients/callers.

Answer (score 2):

You can terminate the current program / JVM with `System.exit`

```
java.lang.System.exit(0 /* Status */ );
```

If you don't want to exit then you have to use return.

in a void method do

```
int value;
value = method();
return;
```

Or if method has the same return signature as the current method

```
int value;
return value = method();
```

Comment: Ok but this was not exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: and how exactly is this helping?

Comment: Frozendragon - The only other option is to throw and exception ( either in method or in the calling function ). Otherwise, no you cannot do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Add if condition value=youexpected return;